# Difference between virtualenv and "virtualenv ."

Tags: python, linux, virtualenv

A command line instruction on this page
https://github.com/plumi/plumi.app/blob/master/docs/INSTALL.rst

is "virtualenv ."

That is, there's a period after a space.

I can't find any documentation for including a period after virtualenv in this manner.

Do you think this matters, does it make no difference if one simply writes virtualenv without the period?

Comment: `.` is the current directory. It creates a virtualenv in the current folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
virtualenv --help
Usage: virtualenv [OPTIONS] DEST_DIR
```

From a forum [post](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/what-does-a-single-period-mean-in-bash-577903/):

```
"." (dot) has many meanings:
In a pathname it means "current directory"--eg. ./filename
As a prefix to a filename, it causes it to be hidden--eg. .filename
It is a synonym for the "source" command--used to pull an executable file into a script.--eg: . execfile (note the space)
In a regular expression it matches any single character.
```

As blender pointed out, the command `virtualenv .` will make the virtualenv in the current directory